# Does anyone here know how can we extract Lambda from the following equation

Tags: equation-solving, trigonometry

I am working on an estimation problem where I have the following

[image]

Code is

```
A = 1 + Pi*Csc[(1 + Pi)*\[Lambda]]^2*
    (Pi + Sin[2*(1 + Pi)*\[Lambda]])
```

Can anyone help me how can we extract $\lambda$ from this equation in Mathematica?

Comment: Try   : `Solve`  or `Reduce` ?

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk i want lemda on one side and rest on other side so that I can calculate lemda which is my requirement

Comment: Execute this in Mathematica:`Solve[A == 
  1 + Pi*Csc[(1 + Pi)*\[Lambda]]^2*(Pi + 
      Sin[2*(1 + Pi)*\[Lambda]]), \[Lambda]]` then you  have the answer?

Comment: Sadly it yields empty brackets @MariuszIwaniuk

Comment: On MMA 12.2.0 **works fine**.Try on wolfram cloud: https://develop.wolframcloud.com.  You must only sign in.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk I solved it in Mathematica however it is beyond my understanding like it's so lengthy and a huge thing?  Is it a series?

Comment: You might get a simpler result if there are known constraints on `A` and/or `lambda`

Comment: Look at the plot of `lambda` as a function of `A`, i.e.,  `ParametricPlot[{1 + Pi*Csc[(1 + Pi)*\[Lambda]]^2*(Pi + Sin[2*(1 + Pi)*\[Lambda]]), \[Lambda]}, {\[Lambda], 0, 2 Pi}, WorkingPrecision -> 15, AspectRatio -> 1, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"A", "\[Lambda]"}]`

Answer (score 1):

Help Solve with TrigExpand.

Function is periodic, lets find period.

```
A[\[Lambda]_] = 1 + Pi*Csc[(1 + Pi)*\[Lambda]]^2*
   (Pi + Sin[2*(1 + Pi)*\[Lambda]])

Plot[A[\[Lambda]], {\[Lambda], 0, 3}]

\[Lambda]period = 
   lap /. First@
Solve[0 < lap < 1 && A[1/2] - A[1/2 + lap] == 0 && 
  A[1/2] - A[1/2 + 2 lap] == 0 // TrigExpand, lap]

(*   (-1 + 3*Pi - 
  4*ArcTan[Sec[1/2]*Sqrt[Cos[1/2]^2 + Sin[1/2]^2] - 
        Tan[1/2]])/(2 + 2*Pi)   *)

\[Lambda]sol[AA_] = \[Lambda] /. Solve[TrigExpand[
     0 < \[Lambda] < 2*\[Lambda]period && 
 A[\[Lambda]] == AA], \[Lambda], Reals]

(*   {ConditionalExpression[
 (2*Pi + 2*ArcTan[Root[Pi^2 + 4*Pi*#1 + 
                (4 - 4*AA + 2*Pi^2)*#1^2 - 4*Pi*#1^3 + 
                Pi^2*#1^4 & , 1]])/(1 + Pi), 
 Element[ArcTan[Root[Pi^2 + 4*Pi*#1 + 
             (4 - 4*AA + 2*Pi^2)*#1^2 - 4*Pi*#1^3 + 
             Pi^2*#1^4 & , 1]], Reals] && AA > Pi^2], 
ConditionalExpression[
 (2*Pi + 2*ArcTan[Root[Pi^2 + 4*Pi*#1 + 
                (4 - 4*AA + 2*Pi^2)*#1^2 - 4*Pi*#1^3 + 
                Pi^2*#1^4 & , 2]])/(1 + Pi), 
 Element[ArcTan[Root[Pi^2 + 4*Pi*#1 + 
             (4 - 4*AA + 2*Pi^2)*#1^2 - 4*Pi*#1^3 + 
             Pi^2*#1^4 & , 2]], Reals] && AA > Pi^2], 
ConditionalExpression[
 (2*ArcTan[Root[Pi^2 + 4*Pi*#1 + (4 - 4*AA + 2*Pi^2)*
                #1^2 - 4*Pi*#1^3 + Pi^2*#1^4 & , 3]])/(1 + Pi), 
 Element[ArcTan[Root[Pi^2 + 4*Pi*#1 + 
             (4 - 4*AA + 2*Pi^2)*#1^2 - 4*Pi*#1^3 + 
             Pi^2*#1^4 & , 3]], Reals] && AA > Pi^2], 
ConditionalExpression[
 (2*ArcTan[Root[Pi^2 + 4*Pi*#1 + (4 - 4*AA + 2*Pi^2)*
                #1^2 - 4*Pi*#1^3 + Pi^2*#1^4 & , 4]])/(1 + Pi), 
 Element[ArcTan[Root[Pi^2 + 4*Pi*#1 + 
             (4 - 4*AA + 2*Pi^2)*#1^2 - 4*Pi*#1^3 + 
             Pi^2*#1^4 & , 4]], Reals] && AA > Pi^2]}   *)

pl1 = Plot[Evaluate[\[Lambda]sol[AA]], {AA, 0, 200}, 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> {Green, Red, Orange, 
     Magenta}]

pl2 = ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{A[\[Lambda]], \[Lambda]}], 
 {\[Lambda], 0, 3}, AspectRatio -> 1]

Show[pl2, pl1]
```